# Is there a way in Sinatra to separate helpers used in views and helpers used in routes?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

All helpers in Sinatra can be accessed from both my HAML code and my routes. But I'm finding myself writing two completely separate sets of code for these two.

Ideally I'd like to keep them apart.  Currently I have them in two different directories, but that seems kind of pointless. Can anyone suggest a way I can limit the potential damage caused by namespace collision?

At first I thought modules.  From the Sinatra readme:

```
module FooUtils
  def foo(name) "#{name}foo" end
end

module BarUtils
  def bar(name) "#{name}bar" end
end

helpers FooUtils, BarUtils
```

But is there any point in actually doing this? Aren't they going to have to share the same namespace inside my Sinatra app?

Comment: Is it method name collision you're worried about?

Comment: @iain. Partly. But it's also about basic separation of responsibility. Different things should not be lumped together; that's not good design. (I'm afraid my question has been edited to make it look as if I'm only worried about namespace collision.)

Comment: I think you'll need to add some more problems it may be causing you, as there are quite a few strategies you could use to separate things (or not) but obviously, some of them are more appropriate than others to different situations.

Comment: @iain: well, I don't have any specific examples other than namespace collision. I just don't want to lump the code that should be accessed in the view in with the code that shouldn't, because I think it's bad design. What if I accidentally call the latter in a view?

Comment: They're both in the same scope ([Request/Instance scope](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Request/Instance%20Scope)), so if you're worried about calling the wrong thing in a view then the best advice I can give is to write a spec for the views that checks everything looks fine. Or to be as careful as we wish OpenSSL programmers to be :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### Some tentative and not-entirely-satisfactory answers:

1) Methods defined in the same way as helpers but without the call to `Sinatra::helpers` don't appear to be accessible from views, but *are* accessible from within the Sinatra application block. That is:

```
require 'sinatra'

module Sinatra

  module MyThing

    # Helper classes and methods go here

  end

  helpers MyThing  # <- leave this out if you don't want access from views
end
```

2) You can of course also have `MyThingHelpers` and `MyThingLib` modules, instead of just `MyThing`, to prevent namespace collision.

3) And you can put them in separate subdirectories.

I've yet to be convinced that these represent a *comprehensive* solution to my concerns. Time and testing will tell, I suppose, unless someone can give me a better answer here.